# Findbugs for Git Pull Request

Tags: git, jenkins, findbugs, pull-request, static-code-analysis

Is there a way to setup Findbugs (or any other static code analysis tool) in Jenkins to analyse the incoming pull requests and compare the result with the main branch? My goal is to reject pull requests which increase the number of static code analysis issues.

Comment: I think.... there **might be no way** (I am glad...if any one can come with the way...)

Comment: Pull requests have Travis CI integration. Maybe you can setup a Travis configuration that does what you want. Not sure if it's possible or easy but worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I'm kind of stuck with Jenkins.

Comment: Are you having a maven-job ins Jenkins?

Comment: 4 years later, and I'm still looking for the same thing. :-) Another alternative would be to only analyze the _code changes_ like SonarQube, and make sure the _changes_ does not have any (major) violations. That tool is however not free if you want Github integrations with PR comments on found issues. And for Java 10+ I have not found any working third party tool that does the github integration either as of today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can realize your idea by using the Maven-plugins checkstyle, findbugs and pmd (-cpd).

Each of this plugin has a ":check"-mojo, which can fail the build - based on zero or configured rule-violations.

- [checkstyle check-mojo](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html)
- [findbugs check-mojo](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/check-mojo.html)
- [pmd check-mojo](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/cpd-check-mojo.html)
- [pmd-cpd check-mojo](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/check-mojo.html)

This mojos are bound to the maven-"verify"-phase, so *mvn verify* will do the job - or you execute the mojos directly within your jenkins-build (job-configuration "Build" -> "Goals and options" -> *mvn verfiy*, or *mvn test checkstyle:check*).

The plugins have different ways to configure a fail.

For example, checkstyle-plugin has [maxAllowedViolations](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html#maxAllowedViolations)-configuration-parameter. So you can set this parameter to your current violations-count, and use *mvn verfiy* or *mvn checkstyle:check* to let your build fail, if a new violation occurs. Of course, you would have to increase this parameter every time a checkstyle-violation is fixed.

In fingbugs-plugin, your build would have to be free of violations, before you can use *mvn findbugs:check*.

Comment: I will accept this answer, because apparently that is closest thing to a solution. Even though both solutions are not really practicable. Adjusting checkstyle maxAllowedViolations every time is maintenance I don't want to do and findbugs violations having to be at zero means there are checks I have to exclude from the Jenkins build, which is actually what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Actually, I don't think pmd is necessary for the checks you suggest. findbugs and checkstyle have themselves options to fail a maven build.